# SQL multiple search in where clause

Tags: sql-server, wildcard, where-clause

Needed help in using multiple search in where clause:

Trying to write a query which would return tickets in 'Closed Complete', 'Closed Incomplete', 'Closed Skipped' and exclude rows which contains Project in a column but it shouldn't  exclude if contains projector, ms project, project 2016, projector

Here's the query I have so far:

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here

```html
Select 
CONCAT(YEAR(a.[closed_at]),'-',DATENAME(MONTH,a.[closed_at])) as [Year_Month],
a.[Number],
a.[closed_at],
b.[Region], 
b.[Tower_Name],
a.[Short_description],
a.[description]
from [dbo].[sc_task_master_data] a
right join [dbo].[Master_Assignee_list] b
on a.[assignment_group]=b.Assignee_Group_Name
where a.[state] IN ('Closed Complete','Closed Incomplete','Closed Skipped')
and a.[short_description] not like '%project%'
and a.[short_description] like '%project 2%'
and a.[short_description] like '%MS Project%'
and a.[short_description] like '%PROJECT 20%'
and a.[short_description] like '%project installation%'
and a.[short_description] like '%Microsoft Project%'
and a.[short_description] like '%Projector%'
and a.[number] in ('SCTASK0050503',  'SCTASK0050510','SCTASK0051162')
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are going to need to use OR instead of AND for the short_description. You can't have a value be more than one value at a time. Also...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: @SeanLange I tried that; but then it returns rows which are not in ('Closed Complete','Closed Incomplete','Closed Skipped')

Comment: As Sean Lange has said, you need to use `OR` instead of `AND` for `short_description`, but you can enclose these inside parenthesis in order to `AND` them with your other clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause includes only `AND`s which mean that the conditions before and after must match.

You can modify your statement to include parenthesis which effectively group the clauses together to have a single logical outcome, something like:

```
where a.[state] IN ('Closed Complete','Closed Incomplete','Closed Skipped')
and (a.[short_description] not like '%project%'
or a.[short_description] like '%project 2%'
or a.[short_description] like '%MS Project%'
or a.[short_description] like '%PROJECT 20%'
or a.[short_description] like '%project installation%'
or a.[short_description] like '%Microsoft Project%'
or a.[short_description] like '%Projector%')
and a.[number] in ('SCTASK0050503',  'SCTASK0050510','SCTASK0051162')
```

Note the parenthesis in the second and penultimate lines, which group those clauses together so that it is will be true if *any* of them are true.